# jersey api Client not working in wildfly 9 server

Tags: java, jersey, wildfly, jboss6.x, jersey-client

I recently migrated to WildFly 9 Server. But the jersey API Client is not working on the WildFly 9 Server. Please find the code below:

**module.xml** file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sun.jersey">

                <resources>
                    <resource-root path="jersey-core-1.4.jar"/>
                    <resource-root path="jersey-client-1.4.jar"/>

                </resources>
                <dependencies>
                    <module name="javax.api" services="import"/>
                    <module name="javax.transaction.api" services="import"/>
                    <module name="javaee.api" services="import"/>
                    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" services="import"/>
                    <module name="org.jboss.vfs" services="import"/>
                    <module name="org.jboss.msc" services="import"/>
                    <module name="org.hibernate" services="import"/>
                    <module name="javax.el.api" services="import" export="true"/>
                    <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" services="import" export="true"/>
                </dependencies>

            </module>
```

**Code :**

```
Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://www.sampleUrl.com/api/Details.asp");
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        queryParams.add("KEY", XYZ);
        queryParams.add("ID", ABC);
        queryParams.add("Phone", 123456);
        String response = webResource.queryParams(queryParams)
                .accept("text/xml").get(String.class);
```

The above code worked fine in JBoss 6, but its not working after migrating into WildFly. Are there any changes to be made in the code?

when i run above code, it's not throwing any exception and it's not reading the lines after client creation.

Comment: Why don't you just use the standard JAX-RS client. In JAX-RS 2.0 (which Wildfly uses) there is a standard client API. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I know for now JAX-RS 2.0 is not providing a pluggable mechanism to switch providers.

While JPA for example provide this mechanism and this is why you can switch between EclipseLink, Hibernate or OpenJPA on any app server.

It maybe included in JAX-RS 2.1 [The request is already created](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-488)

References:

https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/issues/93

https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/issues/324